# Why does the same Debian release have different kernel versions?

Tags: debian

I have two Debian 7 machines and one of those reports "3.2.60-1+deb7u3" as its kernel release and other one reports "3.2.54-2" as its kernel release. Why does the same Debian release have different kernel versions?

Comment: I run Debian 7. I think these are just the difference between security fixes. Actually the name of the package is `linux-image-3.2.0-4`, which is a little odd. I don't know the explanation of the numbering scheme, but no doubt Ben Hutchings would explain if someone asked him.

Comment: PS. Sent en email to Ben. If he replies, I'll update.

Comment: Isn't that just because one is updated and the other isn't?

Answer (score 1):

For Debian 7 (Wheezy), `3.2.60-1+deb7u3` is from  the package `linux-image-3.2.0-4-486`- Do a `dpkg -l|grep linux-image` on the other machine and check if it uses the same kernel package. If it does, use apt or aptitude to update the machine.

Comment: I see. So over the time, packages in Debian release(Wheezy, Squeeze, etc) repository will be updated and kernel is no exception? And in some point, when the new Debian release is out, the packages will no be update in old Debian release repository and one should consider upgrading the system?

Comment: Correct, the kernel is updated just like other packages.

When a new stable is released, the old one is renamed to oldstable, but it's notoutright  abandoned: Oldstable gets security updates for 2 years after the release of the next stable.

Comment: I see. If even the kernel is updated just like any other package, then how does Debian differ from distributions with a rolling release? So far I thought that all the for example Debian Wheezy users have exactly the same kernel and other software versions and they only receive security-updates to their packages.

Comment: In Debian stable, you get security updates but no new versions while in a rolling release distro you would get both:

Using Debian stable, you're "stuck" to 3.2.xx while a rolling release distro would give you something recent (probably 3.16.x at the time of writing).